# RabbitMQ & SpringBoot logging

Tags: spring-boot, logging, rabbitmq, amqp, elastic-stack

I am sending logs from a spring boot app to rabbitMq but I can't find a way to send these logs in json format (because i want to get them in elasticsearch as documents)

My log4j.properties are:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, consoleAppender, amqp
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t [%c] <%m>%n
log4j.appender.amqp=org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender

log4j.appender.amqp.host=localhost
log4j.appender.amqp.port=5672
log4j.appender.amqp.username=guest
log4j.appender.amqp.password=guest
log4j.appender.amqp.virtualHost=/

log4j.appender.amqp.exchangeName=logs_exchange_fin
log4j.appender.amqp.exchangeType=direct

log4j.appender.amqp.routingKeyPattern=service-2

log4j.appender.amqp.declareExchange=true

log4j.appender.amqp.durable=true
log4j.appender.amqp.autoDelete=false

log4j.appender.amqp.contentType=text/plain
log4j.appender.amqp.generateId=false
log4j.appender.amqp.deliveryMode=PERSISTENT

log4j.appender.amqp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.amqp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t [%c] <%m>%n
```

The pattern of the logs is: `%d %p %t [%c] <%m>%n`

Comment: Hi, hope [this post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/10/log-management-spring-boot-applications-logstash-elastichsearch-kibana/) may help you.

Comment: thanks, that answers a part of the problem